# Pycharm, opencv fails to load dll, works on prompt

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

After installing miniconda with python 3.7 I do the following:

```
conda create --name opencv_test python=3.7
conda activate opencv_test
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

Then to test the environement I do:

```
python
>>> import cv2
>>> exit()
```

Everything goes according to plan

Then if I launch PyCharm or vs code, set my new environment as the interpreter and create a simple file that contains only

```
import cv2
```

On launch I get:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

**What I learned from the internets:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349669/dll-load-failed-when-import-cv2-opencv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760955/import-cv2-dll-load-failed), all those posts refer to a problem that seems similar, the difference being that the issue for me only happens when using IDEs

**What I tried before posting here:**

1. Recreating the environment multiple times switching channels.
2. As it seemed to be a path issue, I added the paths which contained opencv dll to the environment paths in PyCharm settings one at a time

**What I just tried after spending a considerable amount of time creating this post:**

```
conda update conda
```

This weirdly downgrades python to 3.6

```
conda create --name opencv_test_2 python=3.6
conda activate opencv_test_2
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

This seems to fix all the issues but:

- I don't know what just happened and why the issue only appeared on IDEs
- I'd like to use python 3.7

So in short, why when using python 3.7 and PyCharm I seem to be unable to import opencv even if it works on command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to activate the env from terminal, then start your pycharm.exe in the same terminal. Or you can set python project environment (opencv_test/xxx/bin/python.exe )in you pycharm.

Comment: @knight, sorry for the delay. Thank you it's a workaround but launching the program from an activated environment seems to work (not activating it in the options). I still don't understand the issue and how it will affect if I send my code/environement  to people